# How to deploy multiple moqui wars on Tomcat

Tags: moqui

I have two war files moquiA.war and moquiB.war. Now I want to access different instances via different URLs say

http://localhost:8080/moquiA
http://localhost:8080/moquiB

When tried deploying both wars, I was unsuccessful. Anyone tried this?

Additional Details:

I tried deploying a war file on Tomcat other than ROOT, still its is not working. After bit research I feel getPathInfoList (WebFacadeImpl.groovy) might be responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at conf/server.xml:

```
 <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

You can nest  elements within the  element and have different ones corresponding to different virtual hosts, different appBase's etc.

[enter link description here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html)